# Mysql: how can `natural join` using `join_condition`?

Tags: mysql, join

In Mysql, I found the `natural join` syntax is:

```
`table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor`,
```

but other `join` types like `inner` or `outer` join can use `join_conditon`, like the syntax:

```
`table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition`,
```

so how can I use `join_condition` in `natural join`? Is there some alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

A natural join has an implicit join condition, equality on all columns with the same name.

If you want some other join condition, don't use a natural join. If a natural join's implicit join condition is what you want, use that. In general, it's probably easier for everyone to understand if you don't use a natural join and make your join condition explicit.

Comment: But I read the book 'Database System Concept', in the section `3.3.3
The Natural Join`, there is a select clause `select name, title
from (instructor natural join teaches) join course using (course_id);`, in the book, it says:  >To provide the benefit of natural join while avoiding the danger of equating
attributes erroneously, SQL provides a form of the natural join construct that
allows you to specify exactly which columns should be equated. @tpdi

Comment: In that example, there are two joins, of instructor to teaches, then the result of that join to course. The 'a form... equated' part is talking about the `join... on` form.